# Execute Google Assistant programmatically

Tags: java, android

Instead of saying "OK Google", I would like to open Google Assistant by clicking on a button in my own app.

So when in my app that button has been clicked, the user doesn't need to say "Ok Google". They will just simply press the button, then Google Assistant will start and then they can say whatever they want to say. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activity action `android.intent.action.VOICE_ASSIST` can be used to search on the **internet** for specific keywords. For example, it can be said "What's the current date?", then [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%27s%20the%20current%20date&rlz=1C1CHBD_deCH864CH864&oq=what&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i59l2j69i65j69i60l3.1481j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) will be opened, and the current date will also be spoken. Or you can ask anything. As long as Wikipedia is first listed on Google, a brief summary of Wikipedia's content will be spoken. If there is no answer from Wikipedia or from Google itself, the entry will be searched on the search engine of Google, but there is silence.

This is how it should be used:

```java
Intent googleAssistant = new Intent("android.intent.action.VOICE_ASSIST");
startActivity(googleAssistant);
```

You can also use other actions. For instance `com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION`, if you want to search for a place or `android.intent.action.SET_ALARM` to set an alarm.

However, this will not be the best answer since it will not work exactly the same as Google Assistant. So the entertainment part (e.g. "Tell me a joke") cannot be used.

**References**

- [Voice Actions Guide (Google Assistant)](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system)
- [List of Android Actions](https://gist.github.com/zr0n/dfa1afadf7e785e25d53fc2af7c4eee2)

Answer (score 0):

There is an specific Intent to run voice search.

```kotlin
Intent(Intent.ACTION_ASSIST)
    //add below extra if you want trigger search with keyboard
    //without it it will launch katniss voice search
    .apply { putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ASSIST_INPUT_HINT_KEYBOARD, true) }
    .run { context.startActivity(this) }
```